# Codigo de C funciona diferente en servidor

Tags: c

Tengo un problema y es que en un ejercicio cuando lo pruebo en mi Linux local (el Linux integrado en Windows 11) el ejercicio funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando subo el script en el servidor Linux y el programa ya no funciona correctamente, es decir, se queda pillado en un bucle encargado de leer un archivo csv. Es en el bucle `while` de `!feof` a partir donde el codigo me va mal y se queda pillado. Sabe alguien porque puede ser o la diferencia de hacerlo en local o en el servidor?

La funcion se llama parser.c el arhcivo se abre desde un main y se cierra ahí.

Este es el codigo.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxLinea 2048
#define MaxCampos 15
#define Maxlinea2 5000

int parser(FILE* file){
       char linea1[MaxLinea];
    char linea2[MaxLinea];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
    char salida[Maxlinea2];

    
    fgets(linea1,MaxLinea,file);
    while(linea1[i] != '\n'){/*contamos cuantos campos va a existir*/
        if(linea1[i] == ','){
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    j++;
    if(j>15){/*si hay mas de 15 retornamos puesto que no se puede mas de 15.*/
        return -1;
    }
    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(linea2,MaxLinea,file);
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
   while (linea2[c] != '\0')/*cuando la segunda fila acabe termina el bucle.*/
    {
        while(linea1[a] !=',' && linea1[a] != '\0' &&linea1[a] != '\n'){/*metemos caracteres de linea1 hasta que haya una coma*/
            salida[b]=linea1[a];
             b++;
             a++;
            }
        salida[b] = ':';/*insertamos :*/
        b++;
        salida[b] = ' ';/*insertamos espacio*/
        a++;
        b++;
        
        while(linea2[c]!=',' &&  linea2[c] !='\0' && linea2[c] != '\n'){/*metemos caracteres de linea2 hasta que haya una coma.*/
            salida[b] = linea2[c];
            c++;
            b++;

        }
        c++;
        salida[b]=';';/*insertamos ;*/
        b++;
        salida[b]= ' ';/*insertamos espacio*/
        b++;
        
    }
    salida[b] ='\0';
    salida[b-1]='\0';
    salida[b-2]= '\0';
   printf("%s\n", salida);
   for(a=0;a<Maxlinea2;a++){
   salida[a]='\0';
   }
   for(a=0;a<Maxlinea2;a++){
   linea2[a]='\0';
    }
    }
   return 0;

}
```

de un archivo csv así :

```
title,album,duration,release,artist,type
Black Hole Sun,Superunknown,05:06,1994,Soundgarden,Rock
Smells Like Teen Spirit,Nevermind,05:01,1991,Nirvana,Grunge
Breed,Nevermind,03:03,1991,Nirvana,Grunge
Lithium,Nevermind,04:17,1991,Nirvana,Grunge
Once,Ten,03:51,1991,Pearl Jam,Grunge
Even Flow,Ten,04:53,1991,Pearl Jam,Grunge
Alive,Ten,05:40,1991,Pearl Jam,Grunge
Jeremy,Ten,05:18,1991,Pearl Jam,Grunge
Forty Six & 2,Aenima,06:04,1994,Tool,Metal Progresivo
Lateralus,Lateralus,09:24,2001,Tool,Metal Progresivo
```

En local me devuelve esto que es lo correcto:

```
title: Black Hole Sun; album: Superunknown; duration: 05:06; release: 1994; artist: Soundgarden; type: Rock
title: Smells Like Teen Spirit; album: Nevermind; duration: 05:01; release: 1991; artist: Nirvana; type: Grunge
title: Breed; album: Nevermind; duration: 03:03; release: 1991; artist: Nirvana; type: Grunge
title: Lithium; album: Nevermind; duration: 04:17; release: 1991; artist: Nirvana; type: Grunge
title: Once; album: Ten; duration: 03:51; release: 1991; artist: Pearl Jam; type: Grunge
title: Even Flow; album: Ten; duration: 04:53; release: 1991; artist: Pearl Jam; type: Grunge
title: Alive; album: Ten; duration: 05:40; release: 1991; artist: Pearl Jam; type: Grunge
title: Jeremy; album: Ten; duration: 05:18; release: 1991; artist: Pearl Jam; type: Grunge
title: Forty Six & 2; album: Aenima; duration: 06:04; release: 1994; artist: Tool; type: Metal Progresivo
title: Lateralus; album: Lateralus; duration: 09:24; release: 2001; artist: Tool; type: Metal Progresivo
```

Pero en el server solo me devuelve la primera linea y el bucle se queda pillado sin terminar.

Comment: No conocemos el código ni el error. Complicado, colega.

Comment: @Alfabravo: ha añadido el código (pero no te ha avisado en comentario)

Answer (score 1):

```c
   for(a=0;a<Maxlinea2;a++){
       linea2[a]='\0';
   }
```

no se corresponde con la declaración `char linea2[MaxLinea];`.

En local parece que continua después de ir escribiendo `\0`s en zonas desconocidas :-( El servidor es más sano y te para en seco al final de `parser()` (por tanto puedes leer la primera línea).